# Is it possible to set the Created By user when a record is created by Apex?

Tags: apex, trigger, system-fields

We have an old trigger that is set to run on the insertion of a custom object.
Recently, the handler was updated to create related records of a different object.
We've noticed that the "Created By" user for these different objects is an older System Administrator (perhaps they wrote the trigger initially?).

We also have a Machine User, and the team lead would like these new records to be created by Machine User.
I've read that you cannot change the Created By on existing records, that's fine, but I cannot seem to find any information on if it is possible to set the information moving forward.
I also know that the field cannot be written explicitly and retrieves a "Field is not writeable: myObject__c.CreatedById" error.

If I could log in as the Machine User and recreate the trigger, would that technically work?
Is there a way to adjust the Apex so that the "Created By" (<s>maybe a running user?</s> nope, can only be used in testing) on these records moving forward is the Machine User instead of the old System Admin?

**Is it possible to set the Created By user when a record is created by Apex?**

Comment: What is the stimulus for this trigger? Is it record creation via the SFDC UX or via some 3rd party integration. Your comment make me think the latter. In that case, it is the running user of that integration which depends on the nature of how that integration works - does it have a dedicated integration user or did it default to the user who installed the package?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please find below answers to your questions to the best of my knowledge:

If I could log in as the Machine User and recreate the trigger, would that technically work?

- No , record `CreatedBy` field does not depend on the trigger code author.
  It depends on the current running user.

Is there a way to adjust the Apex so that the "Created By" (maybe a running user?) on these records moving forward is the Machine User instead of the old System Admin?

- For this , you need to check how records are created. Possibly some integration is creating records using the old user. You may need to check on those lines.

Is it possible to set the Created By user when a record is created by Apex?

- No , it cannot be directly set. There is a separate feature which you can refer [here](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000386065&type=1)

Comment: Interesting.. "For this , you need to check how records are created. Possibly some integration is creating records using the old user."  The records are coming in through Qualtrics, some sort of sync workflow.  I'll take a look and see if it's possible to change.

Comment: I've signed into Qualtrics as the machine user and copied the existing workflow so that the machine user is the new owner of the workflow.  Now it's saying that the records are created by ME?  I don't even have a Qualtrics account..

Comment: I do not have much idea about Qualtrics but just copying the workflow will not help.
I think you would need to change configuration for Salesforce user in Qualtrics.
I found this doc which helps in setting up Salesforce user Auth in Qualtrics - https://appexchange.salesforce.com/partners/servlet/servlet.FileDownload?file=00P3000000RRIdNEAX